# Grab checkbox name at runtime in android

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I am looping through a list of checkboxes upon click of a button.  What I am looking to do is grab the name of the checkbox at runtime to strip out an integer value specified within the name.  I am not looking to get the value nor the id.  So in the strings.xml file, `<string name="checkList1">Pain assessment.</string>`, I am trying to get checkList1 at run time.  I can get the text without a problem.   Currently I am looping through the view elements with the code below:

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Root);

            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                View v1 = root.getChildAt(i);
                Class c = v1.getClass();

                if (c == CheckBox.class)
                {
                    CheckBox thisBox = (CheckBox)v1;

                    if (thisBox.isChecked())
                    {
                        String text = (String)thisBox.ge;

                        DoDailyCheckListUpdate(thisBox.isChecked(),checkBoxCount);
                        countItemsFinished++;
                    }

                    checkBoxCount++;
                }
            }
```

What I am looking for is to somehow get the name of Checkbox thisBox.  So when it loops through and hits the Pain Assessment checkbox, I want to be able to pull out checkList1.   Without going as far as ripping through the strings.xml file based on the text I find to get the name, I was hoping maybe there was a simpler solution that I maybe overlooking.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: you could add a tag to the check box and then get the name of the checkbox from the tag ??

Comment: A set tag could work but I'd have to hard code the name within the tag being set.  I was trying to avoid having to do any type of hard coding as it seems to deviate away from the standards.  If it is the only best option than obviously I'd have to take that approach.

Comment: You could use an XML Parser at start up to read through your strings.xml file and build a hashmap of value/name. It would then be a simple case of calling .get() on the hashmap.

Comment: I went with Andros answer which was, I believe, where The Unknown was pointing to.  Though the xml parser approach was what I was probably going to lean towards if I hadn't come on and asked this question.

Comment: Though, as I just mentioned below, I am going to dynamically create the checkboxes on the page eventually.  As currently only the updating is dynamic.  So the converting over to dynamic checkbox creation could put a wrinkle into the accepted approach since I won't be able to specify hard coded values.  We shall see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckBox` extends from `TextView` so to retrieve a text from it is quite simple :

```
String text = thisBox.getText().toString();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

If you want to retrieve the key name of the string. I suggest you put it into the tag of the object :

```
thisBox.setTag(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string. checkList1);
```

Retrieve it like that :

```
String text = (String)thisBox.getTag();
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: That gets me "Pain Assessment".  I'm looking to get the actual name from the strings.xml file, not the value.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick.  Those little tid bits of getResources() and other things I'm still getting to know.  Thank you for the information.  It definitely saved time, especially since I woke up at 1:23 am and it is now 4:03 am and I have been puttering around with a side project and well my brain isn't at full gusto.  I'm on cruise control.

Comment: I ran it and it worked as expected.  Thank you again.  I have the updating portion dynamic but not the initial setting of the checkboxes which I was hoping to do in another version.  That might throw a wrinkle into the mix since I won't be able to hard code that checkList1 value.